# Bash warning - argument expected

Tags: linux, bash, if-statement

The bash script bellow takes a MAC address as a variable and finds the IP address corresponding to this MAC address.

```
#!/bin/bash

read address

OUTPUT="$(nmap -sn -n /IP_ADDRESS_RANGE/ | grep -B 2 "$address" | 
grep -e ^.*[0-9].[0-9].[0-9].[0-9] |  awk '{print substr($0,22)}')"


if [ ${OUTPUT} = ""]; then
    echo "not found"
else
    echo "${OUTPUT}"
    arpspoof -i wlan1 -t ${OUTPUT} /GATEWAY/
fi
```

Although it works fine and as expected I get a warning when I execute it and I want to find out how to fix it. The output I get after I enter the MAC address:

```
find.sh: 7: [: =: argument expected
/IP_ADDRESS/
**:**:**:**:*:* **:**:**:**:**:** 0806 42: arp reply 192.168.1.1 is-at **:**:**:**:*:*
```

Comment: What if you use `if [ "${OUTPUT}" = "" ]`?

Comment: @ExplosionPills I get the same warning.

Comment: How about `if [[ "${OUTPUT}" == "" ]]`?

Comment: @ExplosionPills - find.sh: 7: find.sh: [[: not found

Comment: What version of `bash` are you using?

Comment: GNU bash, version 4.2.37(1)-release (i486-pc-linux-gnu)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are multiple errors. [shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net) finds the most obvious ones:

First, you are missing a space here:

```
if [ ${OUTPUT} = "" ]
                   ^--- Required
```

Second, you're missing required quoting:

```
if [ "${OUTPUT}" = "" ]
     ^-- Here -^
```

This should be sufficient to get rid of the error you're seeing.

Here are the other problems:

3. Your regex tries to match an ipv4 address, but instead matches 8 character strings where every other character is a digit.
4. The regex is unquoted, so it could also accidentally match files in the directory and break `grep`
5. You run the script with `sh yourscript`. This only works for `sh` scripts. To run `bash` scripts, use `bash yourscript`.

Comment: I'd argue the best way to run a bash script is to make it executable, then use `/path/to/script` (or `./script` if it's in the current directory).

Answer (score 1):

why not use:

```
[ -z "${OUTPUT}" ]
```

instead? people have also use an ugly trick like this:

```
[ "z${OUTPUT}" = "z" ]
```

to catch empty strings